# NewContractNotFunded error using contracts pallet with version 4.0.0-dev

Tags: smart-contract, rust, rust-ipfs, libp2p

I'm running into an issue where I cannot deploy contracts to my chain, any help is appreciated.

I'm using the same setup as: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/632b32300eb9376767c2ae7b38e79b3f7f5329b1/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L887-L903 (as referenced in the guide here: https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/pallet-design/contracts-pallet/) to integrate with the contracts pallet and rpc (using version 4.0.0-dev) and regardless of the funds held by an account (using `1 << 60` as default balance in my chain spec), I receive the "**NewContractNotFunded**" error when trying to deploy any contract.

Is this an issue with version 4.0.0-dev, or an issue with my setup?
Is a rebase required or is there something else I can do?

My runtime config is here: https://github.com/driemworks/substrate/blob/1fabe26f239166e210f723756812d7eca069e41e/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L270

My initial thoughts were that I need to upgrade my fork to the latest Substrate master branch. However, a dependency in my fork (rust-ipfs) requires an older version of libp2p (0.39.1) that brings in an older version of libp2p-noise (0.32.0). With the changes made to the master branch, compilation fails with:

```
    error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libp2p-noise-0.32.0/src/protocol/x25519.rs:221:45
    |
221 |         curve25519_sk.copy_from_slice(&hash.as_ref()[..32]);
    |                                        -----^^^^^^--
    |                                        |    |
    |                                        |    cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the trait `AsRef`
    |                                        this method call resolves to `&T`
    |
    = note: type must be known at this point
```

I've tried downgrading libp2p back to 0.39.1, however, I encounter the issue regardless.

Comment: Is your contract constructor [payable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862535/1178971)? Is the gas limit high enough for the constructor to be executed? Can you share your contract deploy code?

Comment: It looks like in the example code that a value of [1](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/632b32300eb9376767c2ae7b38e79b3f7f5329b1/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L889) is being passed to the contract as a deposit. Maybe this needs to be increased?

Comment: My contract code is available here https://github.com/driemworks/contracts/blob/dev/test/lib.rs. I made the contract constructor payable AND IT WORKED! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here was to make the contract [payable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862535/1178971).

This is a fairly recent change to ink contracts that requires the constructors to be decorated with `payable` if it's intended for them to receive value (i.e. tokens).

e.g.

```
impl Dapp {
    /// Creates a new payable contract
    #[ink(constructor, payable)]
    pub fn new(initial_supply: Balance) -> Self {
        ...
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/07a8ed9b14a768b87f69dfcd6fedc580c7f36e0e/RELEASES.md#constructors-got-a-new-field-payable-bool